# Error writing url at order by (prestashop)

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a problem:
when I do a search in the search box prestashop gives me some results. then when I order the results by alphabetical order, price or whatever it gives me error 'page unavailable'. 
I detected the error. When I select sort by price (for example) the url is this: 
buscar&search_query=game&submit_search=?orderby=price&orderway=asc&orderway=asc

but it should be as follows:
buscar?search_query=game&submit_search=&orderby=price&orderway=asc&orderway=asc

is rewrite bad the url. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure some module didn't overridden your "override/classes/Link.php" file OR "override/controllers/front/SearchController.php" file. Try disabling overrides by going into Advance Parameters > Performance > Disable overrides(click Yes) and clear cache than check. see below image
[image]